# How can I add tuples in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have a list with tuples in it.

Something like this:

`listnum = [(12,18),(12,20)]`

Is there a way I can add what is in the tuples and make `listnum` into:

`listnum = [30,32]`

Comment: Yep, there is a way. What was your approach and what was the issue with it? Do you have errors?

Comment: I don't even have a start. I realized sum() wouldn't work. If you know the way please let me know.

Comment: start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: In what way would `sum` not work? (Sure, `sum(listnum)` isn't what you want, but can't you think of *some* way to apply `sum` to the problem?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be more specific of what you expect.
If you want your list to be the sum of the numbers in the tuples, here's what you can do:

```
listnum = [sum(x) for x in listnum]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Thank you for the feedback aswell!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
listnum = [(12,18),(12,20)]
required_list = []
for i in range (0, len(listnum)):
    required_list.append(sum(list(listnum[i])))
```

[image]

Comment: This was amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
listnum = [sum(x) for x in listnum]
```

Comment: This also worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to do this:

```
listnum = [(12,18), (12,20)]
res = [x + y for x, y in listnum]
print(res)
[30, 32]
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you have access to numpy, and you need some more flexibility for the number of tuples in your list of numbers, you can convert to numpy array and sum:
    l = numpy.asarray(listnum)
    res = l.sum(axis=-1)

Comment: This returned an empty list for me.

Answer (score 0):

@D.SuperFireball. Here's a way to solve your problem:

```
listnum = [(12,18),(12,20)] 
listnum = [x[0] + x[1] for x in listnum]

# result:
# print(listnum)
# [30, 32]
```